# No soundcard found 12.04 after kernel update

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, pulseaudio, alsa, soundcard

After newest kernel update I have lost my sound card. There is only sound via USB adapter. My headphones or speakers are working only through this device. The sound setting widget doesn't show any sound card device beside USB. I have updated ALSA driver from launchpad and also I have removed the  `~./pulse` directory, I have tried `gnome-alsamixer` ...but my sound card is just gone. I tred to find out if that is some hardware issue or if that is this unlucky kernel update. Take a look on this output of:

```
wget -O alsa-info.sh http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-info.sh && chmod +x ./alsa-info.sh && ./alsa-info.sh
```

http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=80c541c891c4bce51447c9d2f75ea7f9d8b678a4

Here is the alsa-base.conf (with included blacklist):
http://www.pasteall.org/32574

and output of:

```
grep "Codec:" /proc/asound/card*/codec*
grep: /proc/asound/card*/codec*: No such file or directory
```

What else can I provide to find out what's wrong?

Comment: please attach the output of `lspci` in your question.

Comment: oh sure, I forgot that: http://www.pasteall.org/32588

Comment: to complete this report: i had only on-board soundcard/chip.....

Comment: There is no audio device detected in the `lspci` output, so the sound hardware is not detected, have you got any indication in any other ways that the sound chip may be malfunctioning?

Comment: To be sure, what is the output of `lsmod | grep snd`?

Comment: no, i didnt make any physical changes on my hardware at all. I have no idea why that happen. A few days after the latest kernel update i discover that problem. I found changes in the volume indicator, some different layout of that widget and that i couldnt switch to my soundcard device anymore. After i discover that i made several updates how i discribed above. Here is the output of lsmod: http://www.pasteall.org/32593

Comment: your `lsmod` output is consistent with `alsa-info.sh` output, only the usb-sound module is loaded, I'll suggest you to boot with the Ubuntu Live CD or USB and then check the sound-menu or at least the output of `lspci` and look there for the existence of `Audio Device`.

Comment: hello, booting from the livecd gaves me hope, because the soundcard was visible in the sound settings widget and worked.but the lspci output has no audio: http://www.pasteall.org/32613

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information you have provided so far, it appears like the driver module for your internal sound-card has been blacklisted. 
You said that Ubuntu can detect and work with the sound card if you boot from Live CD. So spend the effort to boot from the Live CD again and do a `lsmod | grep snd` there, in this way you'll be able to know what extra modules are loaded there for your internal sound-card.

Then come back to your Ubuntu installation.

Check the file `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-oss.conf` and search there for those missing modules and if found comment them out by placing a `#` before them.
 Finally perform `sudo modprobe <missing modules>` to load them into kernel.

Comment: excuseme, I dont get clear in comparison between this: http://www.pasteall.org/32626 (lsmod | grep snd ) and this: http://www.pasteall.org/32631 (etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-oss.conf). There is also soundcard in blacklist...that confusing me...could you help me to chceck it out? Thank you very much!

Comment: May I know the make/model of your sound card?

Comment: i have on board chip called: CM6501

Comment: Oh, that one is a USB sound card and I should have informed you to search it with `lsusb`, not `lspci`. Also this explains your provided data. From the very first o/p of `alsa-info.sh`, it's sure that your USB sound card is there and detected, with drivers. Just try `alsamixer` instead of gnome-alsamixer, if it detects your sound card, you can select your sound card with `F6`.

Comment: okay, that must be the problem, now i found my card...you are right, this is usb sound...and i could switch it on with alsamixer. but still I have no sound. So it is broken hardware. :(( Thank you very much for the help. I have learned a lot with your help. This is the best support portal in Www

Comment: Most probably your hardware is not broken as you have got sound while booting with live CD. I am upvoting your question so it can get more attention from other people of this community and probably solve this issue.

Comment: What is the status of the small box in the alsamixer ? is it [MM] or [OO] ?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this, that i used to solve a similar issue:

```
sudo modprobe snd-hda-intel
```

and add a line with `snd-hda-intel` at the end of `/etc/modules`.

I think this can solve your issue.

Comment: no, this solution dosn't work for me...so sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

perhaps try this link http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/05/no-soundcards-found-linux-mint-12.html?showComment=1390338718155#c4449143529292145936

worked for me !

Open a terminal (Applications -> Accessories -> Terminal) and type

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

and then change the line from

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pci=use_crs"
```

Save the file.

After saving the file run update-grub

```
sudo update-grub
```

Restart the Machine !